# Fixing Variations Between ios vs Chrome Rendering of SVG on MacOS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic-text

I want to make a dynamically scaling title that grows/shrinks depending on the width of the screen. I also want to make it so that it doesn't apply a word wrap and split the title into 2 or more lines. I am using an SVG trick to make this work.

Consider the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>StackOverflowExample</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.iconify.design/1/1.0.6/iconify.min.js"></script>

</head>

<style>
text {
  font-family: 'Muli';
  font-weight: 600;
  fill: white;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
}
a {
  color: white;
}
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(35, 50, 64, 0.91) 61.95%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.51) 94.56%),
  /* height: 100vh; */
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: black;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: 'Muli';
  color: #ffffff;

  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
</style>

<body class="text-center">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 167 20">
                    <text x="0" y="15">This is a Test Of This T</text>
                </svg>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I got this to work perfectly in Chrome, but then I was surprised that on ios, the last letter would be cut off. Please see screenshot:

IOS:
[image]

Chrome:
[image]

Any ideas on how to make this look correct on both OSes/Browsers? It is supposed to say "This is a test of This T". If you can't see, Chrome correctly resizes this no matter what screen resolution I put this on (smaller or bigger than ios). On ios, it always cuts it off.

I can get this on 1 browser or the other if I change the viewbox parameters, but I can't find any setting that would work for both.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working... for future reference in case anyone else runs into this...

Adding `textLength="167px"` where 167 is the same as your viewbox size fixed the issue. Apparently, ios and MacOS was rendering spacing between the two systems differently causing the issue. Defining a textLength forced it to render more uniformly eliminating the issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>StackOverflowExample</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.iconify.design/1/1.0.6/iconify.min.js"></script>

</head>

<style>
text {
  font-family: 'Muli';
  font-weight: 600;
  fill: white;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
}
a {
  color: white;
}
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(35, 50, 64, 0.91) 61.95%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.51) 94.56%),
  /* height: 100vh; */
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: black;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: 'Muli';
  color: #ffffff;

  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
</style>

<body class="text-center">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 167 20">
                    <text x="0" y="15" textLength="167px">This is a Test Of This T</text>
                </svg>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```